# mysql count distinct with duplicate rows values but different ids

Tags: mysql

I have table

```
id    name    brand_id
1    name1    1
2    name2    2
3    name3    3
4    name3    3
5    name4    1
```

id 3 and id 4 are duplicates with same name and brand_id.
I want to count DISNITC without duplicates - I use query

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand_id, COUNT(brand_id)
FROM z.test
GROUP BY brand_id
```

I get result:

```
brand_id  COUNT(brand_id)
1          2
2          1
3          2 (but I need to get 1 here)
```

Please help solve problem. Thanks.

Comment: use COUNT(DISTINCT name)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> create table tbl(id int, name varchar(10), brand_id int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> (1, 'name1', 1),
> (2, 'name2', 2),
> (3, 'name3', 3),
> (4, 'name3', 3),
> (5, 'name4', 1);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select brand_id, count(distinct name)
> from   tbl
> group by brand_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> brand_id | count(distinct name)
> -------: | -------------------:
>        1 |                    2
>        2 |                    1
>        3 |                    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=693a5d6ca40b1dde97265f7f1b142074)*

Answer (score 1):

You should not have allowed duplicate rows in the first place.  `UNIQUE(name, brand)` would have prevented it.

It sounds like there are 2 steps.

1. Get rid of dups:  `SELECT DISTINCT name, brand_id FROM tbl`
2. Count the frequency of each brand:

   ```
   SELECT  brand,
           COUNT(*)
   FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT name, brand_id FROM tbl ) AS x
   GROUP BY brand_id
   ```